# Does the daily reputation cap also work for reputation loss?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Since there is a maximum reputation cap, is there also a cap for how much can be lost in a day?

Comment: So *that's* what you're doing, you're testing this out?

Comment: @fretje now I have nothing to lose... muhahaha...

Comment: You can always go for an account suspension.

Comment: Dont worry Jon, I dont plan on breaking any rules or doing anything that others dont do.

Comment: When you hit 1 rep, can you post your reputation audit so we can see if it shows what your reputation would be if it could dip below 1?

Comment: @Ether, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

Comment: @Pop: yeah, I know that the graph shows negative reputation, but my question is what the audit would show (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: @Ether, ah, yes, you did say "audit"... well, in that case, you just need to post 175 offensive comments and we can find out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not (until you reach 1 rep). Because there is a -100 penalty for spam/offensive posts, this is probably a good thing.

Answer (score 14):

No, there is no kind of cap for rep loss, except the fact that you can't have negative reputation.

If you get to 1, and keep losing rep, you will stay at 1.

It's like san loss, once you hit rock bottom you can't get any more insane. What were we talking about?

Answer (score 7):

**No**, there is no cap on the rep loss.

(You can't go below 1 though, so actually, the cap is the rep you have now minus 1)