# Is there a negative reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the daily rep cap also work for rep loss?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43959/does-the-daily-rep-cap-also-work-for-rep-loss)

Is there a limit to how much rep I can lose in a day? :)

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45988/will-a-clone-force-stack-overflow-to-open-source) is getting so many downvotes...

Comment: This is a dupe... searching...

Comment: @fretje - I thought so, but can't find it. Maybe it was only said on a related question.

Comment: Here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43959/does-the-daily-rep-cap-also-work-for-rep-loss

Comment: @fretje - obviously in good position to know it was a dupe :]

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. Some points to consider:

- This is meta. Don't be thinking about your rep too much.
- At +1/-7, your rep loss from that question is currently a whooping 4 points.
- If you hit the (positive) rep cap, rep loss from downvotes will be filled up with rep gained from upvotes.